# How can I make the level name be lower-case?

Tags: python, logging

I have a simple logger here. I don't want the levelname to be all caps but lower-case (e.g., `info` instead of the default `INFO`). How can I fix it?

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
chformatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(chformatter)

log.addHandler(ch)

log.error("blah")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look into the [documentation for the logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.addLevelName) and you will find a function that lets you set arbitrary names to logging levels.  Go use that.

```
>>> log.error("blah")
ERROR blah
>>> logging.addLevelName(logging.ERROR, 'error')
>>> log.error("blah")
error blah
```

Comment: Somehow, this doesn't work for me. I call `logging.addLevelName(logging.ERROR, '(E)')` and still get to see `ERROR` in the log for `%(levelname)s`.

Comment: @ulidtko which python version are you using? I can't replicate the exact error even in latest Python version.  Did you run the code posted in the question also?  Paste the entire block of code from the question into the interactive interpreter, and then call `logging.addLevelName` in this answer and you should see the expected output. If you are getting the expected output then it must be some other code or setup in other parts of the program not actually using the `levelname` correctly.

Comment: FYI, I did something like this and found it messes up with sentry.  The level name is used by sentry for mapping log messages to sentry messages.

Answer (score 7):

You can make your own formatter:

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.levelname = record.levelname.lower()
        return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)

chformatter = MyFormatter('%(levelname)s %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(chformatter)
```

Comment: if you want to avoid overwriting the record instance's `levelname` attribute you could use the `copy` module I guess.